# neo4j-cypher: all paths between any two users

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a network, in this an user can be connected in patterns like below.

```
(u:user{guid:123})<-[r]-(mg)<-[r2]-(c)
(u:user{guid:123})<-[r]-(mg)<-[r2]-(c)<-[r3]-(mg2)<-[r4]-(c2)
(u:user{guid:123})<-[r]-(mg)<-[r2]-(c)-[r3]->(mg2)-[r4]->(c2)<-[r5]-(mg3)<-[r6]-(c3)
(u:user{guid:123})<-[r]-(mg)<-[r2]-(c)-[r3]->(mg2)-[r4]->(c2)<-[r5]-(mg3)<-[r6]-(c3)<-[r7]-(mg4)<-[r8]-(c4)
```

'u' is an user with a GUID.

There are multiple pattern of connection between two user.

I want to list all paths between two users given their GUIDs.
Please give some hints to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following query will return all paths with a length between 1 and 5. Adapt if you need a longer path (but it will greatly influence the query performance). You might want to add a direction in your path.

```
MATCH path=(:user{guid:123})-[*1..5]-(:user{guid:456})
RETURN path
```

Comment: Thank you. This returns all paths including paths through other users. How do I avoid paths which involve other users? I want only paths like: (:user{guid:123})<-[r]-(mg)<-[r2]-(c)-[r2]->(mg)-[r]-(:user{guid:456})

Comment: Limit the relationship-types and directions if you don't want to include other users. And you can also add a WHERE NONE(n in nodes(path)[1..-1] WHERE n:user) but that filter will only be applied after producing the paths.

Comment: Thank you,this works for me. Where do I find neo4j-cypher documentation on building these kind of queries?